# Add strings from a text box with backslashes to a database table

Tags: c#, sql-insert, backslash

I'm trying to add a record to a table with data used from a form. My code looks like this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" +
        @"AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\C-Sharp\LockItUp\Lockitup.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string theVault = @lblVault.Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

        string stmt = @"INSERT INTO Users (username,password,folderloc,fullname,email,cellphone)" +
        " VALUES ('" + txtUsrName.Text + "', '" + txtUserPassword.Text + "', '" + theVault + "', '" +
        txtFullname.Text + "', '" + txtEmail.Text + "', '" + txtCellPhone.Text + "')";

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, connect))
        {

            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
                return;
            }
        }

        PanelSwitch("Home");
        RefreshMenu();
    }
}
```

However, every time run it, I get the error message 'String or binary data would be truncated.' I pin pointed the error to the folderloc field. A directory goes in it. I'm currently trying to put the value C:\Development\locker in it, but I keep getting the error. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: For starters, you are *executing user input as SQL code* (also called a SQL injection vulnerability).  Use parameterized queries to treat user input as *values* instead of *code*.  *Then*, once you have control over the code you're executing, *then* it would be time to debug errors in that code.

Comment: This is an indication that your data is too large for one of the fields. try looking at the max size of the fields and the data being passed in to see which field is causing the issue. Also I hope from a security point of view you are not storing passwords as plain text. This is in addition to the very good point from @David

Answer (score 1):

You've got several issues with your code. First, to address the error you are receiving `String or binary data would be truncated`. The reason for this is that the field in the table isn't big enough to store the data. Go into your database and look at the `Users` table and look at each field and make sure the field is defined with enough width to store the data (e.g., look for `VARCHAR(20)` or something and change it to something like `VARCHAR(500)`).

Secondly, as @David suggested, you need to address your issue of SQL Injection. You are directly inserting dynamic values into your SQL statement. This is bad news. Microsoft has a [good article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) on this subject and how to avoid it.

Thirdly, you should not store your passwords as plain text. They should be salted and hashed. Look at [this article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for a good tutorial on this.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you. Both did help. I had the field defined as nchar(10). I changed it to nvarchar(200). Once again, Thanks.